# XMLLINT - Handling ASCII Substitute Character 26

Tags: java, unix

I have a XML containing data between one of the tags which contains ASCII Substitute Character 26.

[ASCII Substitute Character](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-control-characters/substitute-ascii-code-26.html)

I want to pretty print this XML using XMLLINT command. However, the command is failing on the substitute character giving below error:

```
:1: parser error : internal error
```

How to handle this special character in XMLLINT ? My XML is of size 2 GB so its difficult to format it inside the java program which is creating the XML.

The marshallar is XStreamMarshaller which is creating the XML.

How the XML is getting generated: Its a spring batch program which is reading data from a database (from where this ascii character is coming) and creates a XML file using StaxEventItemWriter where the marshaller is XStreamMarshaller..

Comment: If you mean your XML file contains the Unicode character 26, that's simply an invalid XML file (assuming it's XML 1.0 rather than 1.1). If at all possible, you should fix whatever is producing the file.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes.. My XML contains ASCII Character 26 i.e. substitute character.. will it be possible that XMLLINT handles the character if its XML 1.1 ? I have updated how the file is getting created...